# How can I write content when a list item is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm implementing a list of images using the following HTML:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
    <li>t</li>
</ul>
<span id="gallery-prev">Previous</span>

<span id="gallery-next">Next</span>
```

In addition I'd like when I click on a `li`, it shows me a specific content in a `div`.

For example, if I click on `li` number 3 it writes `"#3"` in a `div`.
If I click on `li` number 6 it shows `"#6"` in the same `div`.

This is my current script:

```
var galleryImages = new Array(
    'images/tb_01.jpg',
    'images/tb_02.jpg',
    'images/tb_03.jpg',
    'images/tb_04.jpg',
    'images/tb_05.jpg',
    'images/tb_06.jpg',
    'images/tb_07.jpg',
    'images/tb_08.jpg',
    'images/tb_09.jpg',
    'images/tb_10.jpg',
    'images/tb_11.jpg',
    'images/tb_12.jpg',
    'images/tb_13.jpg');

$('#gallery-next').click(function () {
    if ($('ul#gallery li:last img').length == 0) var curIndex = 0;
    else var curIndex = galleryImages.indexOf(
    $('ul#gallery li:last img').attr('src'));
    $('ul#gallery li').children().remove();
    $('ul#gallery li').each(function (index, el) {
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function () {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
            //$(el).append(this); -- doesn't work
            console.log('appended');
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).attr('src',
        galleryImages[(curIndex + index) % galleryImages.length]);
        //found indexes, will now loop!
        $(el).html(((curIndex + index) % galleryImages.length));
        $(el).append(img); //does work
    });
});
```

Here is the [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CaK3c/)

Comment: As a side-note: Having multiple `var curIndex` within if-else statements is pointless and can lead to confusing logical errors. JavaScript has function scope and when using `var` the declarations are hoisted to the top of their function scope while the assignments stay where they are. Block scope is not yet widely available (well, there is ways) but will be in the next version of ECMAScript through the use of `let` instead of `var`. In general assume function scope only. Declaring your variables at the top of the function ones can help if you are new to languages with no block scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mandatory Vanilla Answer (IE9+ only):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#gallery li");
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        elements[index].addEventListener("click",function() {
            console.log("You have clicked index: "+index);
        }, false);
    })(i);
}
```

Get the elements into a NodeList, iterate with a for loop, and uses a `closure` to track the index of the loop so that the event listener responds to the click, and logs the index you have clicked on.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3CK9/1/)

Comment: your code wont work..also you dont really need closure..some more you need to use `document.querySelectorAll("#gallery li");` to get all `li`

Comment: @Florian you saved him

Comment: Oops, forgot `All`. Thanks Florian, nice save

Comment: @Pilot yeah, I liked the way the answer was going, so just edited.

Comment: I have another question: if I'd like to insert a jquery line after "console.log.." ,could I?
(for example $(".nameOfDiv").css('display','block'))

Comment: This is something you could easily try yourself ;)

Comment: I tried here but it doesn't work! D: (http://jsfiddle.net/3N8bU/)

Comment: Dont use alert like a debugging tool. Use console.log like I did. And it would help to import jQuery in your fiddle. it doesn't magically know these things ;)

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm a nitwit!! Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$("#gallery li").click(function() {
    var number = $(this).index() + 1;
    console.log("You clicked " + number);
});
```

Comment: haha same answer at the exact same time... i can delete mine

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KC5cD/1/)

```
$('#gallery').on('click', 'li', function(){ 
  var index = $(this).index()+1; 
  $(this).text('#'+index);
});
```